# Android how to create popup window

Tags: android, button, popup, window

I need to create a popup window with buttons and a button that will close the popup. I found some tutorials but I couldn't find out how to do the implementation.

What I want to do: Click an action button and the popup shows and when I click the the close button the popup window must close.

There were an onCreate method in the tuorials and I didn't understand how is it called.

Can somebody give an example of an popup implementation or a link to a good tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: could you post your code you try

Comment: refer to this link example of pop up window http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285 this one is a dialog http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: I tried the code from the answer here but I don't know how to call the onCreate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android

Comment: Is the onCreate method from my activity?

Comment: @user3132352 where do you need to show it? In center or Some where?

Comment: If you have found satisfactory answer, accept that answer.
Are you still looking for satisfactory answer?

Comment: [Here is the code to show popup window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38328183/4448757)

Answer (score 7):

```
private void showPopup(){
    Button btn_closepopup=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_closePoppup);
    pwindo=new PopupWindow(layout,480,500,true);
    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 40);
    chartContainer1.addView(mChart);
    btn_closepopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pwindo.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I also need an example of creating the popup.

Comment: please follow this link http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
private void callPopup() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    popupWindow=new PopupWindow(popupView,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,        
        true);

    popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    Name = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.edtimageName);

    ((Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                Name.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    ((Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.cancelbtutton))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```