# AlertDialog Like From Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, android-alertdialog

[image]

I know how to create a Simple alert dialog. 
But I don't have any idea how to create being like this in facebook.
You can see it from your facebook app in your profile and click the ". . ".

How will I able to make like this one?

Comment: make an xml layout and inflate in alert dialog box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

Comment: I have a feeling this is more of a popupwindow than an alertDialog view

Comment: I know how to create custom alert dialog but nothing like that in facebook. Its on the right side of the screen.

Comment: @Simon Do you have a tutorial for popupwindow?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028480/android-how-to-create-popup-window you will just need to showAtLocation at the right place and animate it similar to Facebook once it is shown. I think it is a popupwindow because it looks highly customized. An alert dialog is normally used for alerts where you click OK or Cancel.

Comment: okay thanks. ill try that thank you.